# Java: Find index of first Regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to change a piece of code which includes this:

```
string.indexOf("bc")
```

How can this be changed by a solution that skips the occurrence of "bc" if it is preceded by the letter "a".

I don't want to find these:

abc

but only:

xbc

where x can be anything but a (even empty).

I think I could just put in a condition that checks if the index i-1 == a, and if true call the indexOf method again. But I don't think that would result in very beautiful code.

How would a solution that uses regular expressions look like?

Edit: Just a hint after seeing some responses. It would be nice to get not only the regular expression, but also the required API calls to find the index.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As requested a more complete solution:

```
    /** @return index of pattern in s or -1, if not found */
public static int indexOf(Pattern pattern, String s) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
}
```

call:

```
int index = indexOf(Pattern.compile("(?<!a)bc"), "abc xbc");
```

Comment: Well, my Edit was more a response to the answers that only contained a single regular expression. But thanks anyway, this looks nice.

Comment: if you wanted to do indexing on top of it you could do: 

public static int indexOf(String regex, String s, int index)
{
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        return matcher.find(index) ? matcher.start() : -1;
}

...

int index = indexOf("(?<!a)bc", "abc xbc", 2);

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regex with a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!a)bc
```

Unfortunately to reproduce `.indexOf` with Regex in Java is still a mess:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?!a)bc");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abc xbc");
if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.start();
}
```

Comment: Negative lookbehind seems to hit the nail pretty much. Too bad there isnt a .indexof(Regex) in the API.

Comment: @HansWiener sorry it should be `matcher.find()` (see? It's a mess :) ).

Comment: Ah its just a typo, which version should I accept now? Thers also a typo in the regex expression (missing <)

Comment: Honestly what is the point of finding a match to a reg exp if then there is no way to retrieve the starting or ending index of the pattern found in the String? This is why I refuse to use Pattern and Matcher classes. It's too cryptic and way more frustrating and time-wasting than helpful. You gotta scrub through the String char by char. You complete your objective much faster with much less frustration I promise

Answer (score 2):

To add to Arne's answer - if you wanted to also add indexing:

```
public static int indexOf(String regex, String s, int index)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    return matcher.find(index) ? matcher.start() : -1;
}
```

call:

```
int index = indexOf("(?<!a)bc", "abc xbc", 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to find the String that matches your criteria, and then find the index of that String.

```
int index = -1;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^Aa]?bc");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if (m.find()) {
    index = m.start();
}
```

Something like this. Where 'string' is the text you're searching and 'index' holds the location of the string that is found. (index will be -1 if not found.) Also note that the pattern is case sensitive unless you set a flag.