# JEditorpane vs. JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane

i have to create a project in java swing for my college. An editor of java files with proper text highlighting i.e different colors and fonts for **java keywords**, **java comments** and for **normal text**.
Help me to select one of two styled text component **JEditorpane**  and **JTextPane** provided by java so that i can full-fill the requirements.
**Please tell me suitable difference between these two that in which kind of situation i have to use one of these.**

Comment: read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html , explains well.

Comment: As `JTextPane` is a subclass of `JEditorPane`, the main difference is that `JTextPane` does everything `JEditorPane` does, and then some!

Comment: Which is fast in performance i.e fast while reading contents from file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use either of them, but if it is a rich text editor then I would suggest using the `JTextPane`.

You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400946/how-to-change-the-color-of-specific-words-in-a-jtextpane) topic useful.

Answer (score 32):

Although both support rich text. But there is difference.

**JEditorPane** supports display/editing of HTML.

**JTextPane** is an extension of JEditorPane which provides word processing features like fonts, text styles, colors, etc.