# Build a chat using JEditorPane/JTextPane

Tags: java, chat, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I'm trying build a chat, with a simple server and user interface.
Every user has a name, and I want the user's name appear in red color and bold before his message, every time he sends a message.
Which one (JEditorPane/JTextPane) would be appropriate to my goal? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these components will suite your needs just fine. There is no easy way to say which one is better. You can do some backgroudn research and find all the pros and contras yourself.

Here are a few links that will help you started:

- [JEditorpane vs. JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093851/jeditorpane-vs-jtextpane)
- [How to change the color of specific words in a JTextPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400946/how-to-change-the-color-of-specific-words-in-a-jtextpane)
- http://www.coderanch.com/t/343829/GUI/java/JTextArea-JEditorPane-JTextPane-suited-application
- http://www.javaranch.com/style.jsp
- http://tutiez.com/difference-between-jeditorpane-and-jtextpane.html

Comment: Thank you! I chose JTextPane, but I don't want the name become red and bold while the user typing, I want just send the string to the server with his name first : 
outputString = user.getName() + textArea.getText();
I havn't found good guide for my goal.. Can you suggest me one?

Comment: Since you havent provided any runnable code example, here are a few things that could help you with this. Check these code samples: http://www.coderanch.com/t/341568/GUI/java/JTextArea-changing-color-words and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068398/how-to-add-text-different-color-on-jtextpane

Comment: Thank you.  http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextPanesetCharacterAttributesAttributeSetattrbooleanreplace.htm
This one is a great example. 
Then, I thought to build an append function like in the URL (in the server's code) and just append it to all users. What do you think ? 
:)

Comment: Can you mark as an answer? Thanks :-) Glad I could help.