# creating a chat in java with JTextArea

Tags: java, fonts, chat, jtextarea

i created a chat in java with jtext area.

when some one write a new message, the message appear in the chat in that form:

time username: message (example: 17:00 TheMan: Whats up)

My question is how can i change the font and add bold only in specific places in the text area ( the time and username) while leaving the rest as it was.

hope someone will be able to help.... tnx

Comment: Try JTextPane instead of JTextArea to change text style.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400946/how-to-change-the-color-of-specific-words-in-a-jtextpane)

Answer (score 0):

JTextArea supports simple plain text with simple styling only.

you may need to use JEditorPane or JTextPane instead of JTextArea.

[Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)