# Java syntax highlighting mismatched char

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, defaultstyleddocument

I'm implementing a syntax highlighting by reusing the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400946/how-to-change-the-color-of-specific-words-in-a-jtextpane). The problem is that each char "{,},<,>" is not coloured it is not followed by a non-char. For example in "

```
@Override
    public void insertString (int offset, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException 
      {
            super.insertString(offset, str, a); 
            String text = getText(0, getLength());
            int before = findLastNonWordChar(text, offset);
            if (before < 0) before = 0;
            int after = findFirstNonWordChar(text, offset + str.length());
            int wordL = before;
            int wordR = before;                               
            while (wordR <= after) {
                if (wordR == after || String.valueOf(text.charAt(wordR)).matches("\\W")) {
                    if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(SELECT|WHERE)"))
                        setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attr, false);
                    else if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(\\{|\\}|\\<|\\>)"))
                      setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrRed, false);
                    else
                        setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlack, false);
                    wordL = wordR;
                }
                wordR++;
            }
        }
private int findLastNonWordChar (String text, int index) {
        while (--index >= 0) {
        if (String.valueOf(text.charAt(index)).matches("\\W")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
private int findFirstNonWordChar (String text, int index) {
    while (index < text.length()) {
        if (String.valueOf(text.charAt(index)).matches("\\W")) {
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match angle brackets in Java 8 regular expressions, you must use

```
    .*
```

So use:

```
    .matches("<.*")
```

matches a single angle bracket. Combine this with the regular expression you already have to get a single angle bracket, WITHOUT the double backslash (\).

Comment: I have modified the question since the matched word is "<" followed by a non alphabetic char.

Comment: Is it only one character that is being added on to the end of it? If so, have you tried to limit the match to only a single character (in this case just the '<'), as it should ignore the character after?

Comment: one or more character, I have tried  '<' with no results.

Comment: The problem is more complex than it seems, I'm modifying the question.

Comment: Okay, i understand now, however, this regex should work. Use this:

[link]http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Put the regex in at the top (without double backslash only a single) it will convert it into java regex for you. Have your inputs at the  bottom (with and without spaces), and you will see that the regex is fine, i just tried it for you. Are you sure its not the input you're passing through?