# how can i implement syntax coloring on a jtextpane

Tags: java, swing, code-editor

I'm making a code editor in java, and I ran into a problem while implementing syntax coluring. I could not find anything on the Internet on how to do it. I only found a 6 year old post that did not work.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Refer to this SO question: [How to change the color of specific words in a JTextPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400946/how-to-change-the-color-of-specific-words-in-a-jtextpane) There is also this tutorial. [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: that do not work for me

Comment: (1-) What doesn't work for you? There are multiple answers. I picked one and it worked fine. Of course doing complete syntax coloring is a complex task since you need to handle comments and literals etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first: you need to use a jEditorPane

Second: Create a highlighter like this(you can change the color of the highligthe):

```
DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(new Color(255, 0, 0, 75));
```

Third: to highlight use this

```
 try {
    jEditorPane1.getHighlighter().addHighlight("here put the number of the starting character", "Here put the ending number of character",
                                highlightPainter);
 } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
 }
```

Example.

```
  JEditorPane text = new JEditorPane();
  text.setText(" Hi This is example good");
  DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(new Color(255, 0, 0, 75));
  try {
    jEditorPane1.getHighlighter().addHighlight(3, 7, highlightPainter);
 } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
 }
```

It should apper this underlined: "i This ";