# How do I colorise certain words in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, text-coloring

I have a simple HTML text Editor which I'm trying to convert into an IDE. I'm finished with the basics (Like adding a file browser and running the project). The next obstacle I'm facing is adding themes.

I googled and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea) but it requires adding the text before changing its color. 
What behaviour I want is similar to JetBrains Webstorm (Or IntelliJ IDE):
[image]

This is what it looks like as of now:
[image]

Comment: An IDE requires you to type the text before it can "color" it.  A [JTextPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) uses a [StyledDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html).  You have to modify the `StyledDocument` as the user types.

Comment: You're going to need to take deep dive into the `StyledDocment`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916249/colorpane-grab-strings-of-different-character-possible/15916621#15916621) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948148/jeditorpane-set-foreground-color-for-different-words/18948340#18948340) but I just want to point out that syntax highlight is VERY complex

Comment: I will try viewing IntelliJ and webstorm's source code.

Comment: Highlighting is the easy part. Parsing the text to find the tokens to highlight is the hard part as you need to consider things like multi-line comments, keywords within quotes etc. You can check out my old attempt at a Java syntax highlighter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27338679/131872

Comment: Then maybe have a look at [RSyntaxTextArea](https://bobbylight.github.io/RSyntaxTextArea/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, ill look at it.Gilbert Le Blanc Thank you too, now I get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) mentioned, you can use [RSyntaxTextArea](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea).

From its README:

> RSyntaxTextArea is a customizable, syntax highlighting text component
> for Java Swing applications. Out of the box, it supports syntax
> highlighting for 50+ programming languages, code folding, search and
> replace, and has add-on libraries for code completion and spell
> checking. Syntax highlighting for additional languages can be added
> via tools such as JFlex.

Example Usage:-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.*;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*;

public class TextEditorDemo extends JFrame {

    public TextEditorDemo() {

        JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(20, 60);
        textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
        textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
        RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
        cp.add(sp);

        setContentPane(cp);
        setTitle("Text Editor Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start all Swing applications on the EDT.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TextEditorDemo().setVisible(true));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any "TextPane" alternative

Comment: @RishonJR you cannot do this with `JTextPane` instead use a `jeditorpane`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057567/17022570

Comment: Okay, I will see both Solutions. Let me see if I can migrate to JTextPane.

Comment: @RishonJR ok let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Whoops, a typo there... I meant JTextArea lol. I Can Safely migrate to it without any problems.

Comment: https://www.mp3download.center