# How to capitalize the first letter in custom textview?

Tags: android, textview, capitalize

In Custom TextView suppose if first character as a number then next character would be a character. How to find the first character amoung numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Find index of first Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214245/java-find-index-of-first-regex)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Kotlin you may go for:

Capitalize first word:

```
var str = "whaever your string is..."
str.capitalize()
// Whaever your string is...
```

Capitalize each word

```
var str = "whaever your string is..."
val space = " "
val splitedStr = str.split(space)
str = splitedStr.joinToString (space){
    it.capitalize()
}
// Whaever Your String Is...
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this method by splitting the entire word

```
String input= "sentence";
String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
textview.setText(output);
```

Output:
Sentence

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the inputType parameter in the xml layout file for the TextView. Basically in the layout file where you wish to set the TextView in camel case, add the following line:

```
android:inputType = "textCapWords"
//This would capitalise the first letter in every word.
```

If you wish to only capitalise the first letter in the TextView, use the following instead.

```
android:inputType = "textCapSentences"
//This would capitalise the first letter in every sentence.
```

If you have a textView which has more than one sentence, and you only want to capitalise the first letter in the TextView, I would recommend using code to do this:

```
String[] words = input.getText().toString().split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (words[0].length() > 0) {
    sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[0].charAt(0)) + words[0].subSequence(1, words[0].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)) + words[i].subSequence(1, words[i].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
    }
}
String titleCaseValue = sb.toString();
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function pass your string and return capitalize string.

```
public static String wordCapitalize(String words)
{

    String str = "";
    boolean isCap = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++){

        if(isCap){
            str +=  words.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
        }else{
            if(i==0){
                str +=  words.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
            }else {
                str += words.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
            }
        }

        if(words.charAt(i)==' '){
            Utility.debug(1,TAG,"Value of  i : "+i+" : "+words.charAt(i)+" : true");
            isCap = true;
        }else{
            Utility.debug(1,TAG,"Value of  i : "+i+" : "+words.charAt(i)+" : false");
            isCap = false;
        }
    }
    Utility.debug(1,TAG,"Result : "+str);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
for(Character c : text){
   if(c.isLetter){
     //First letter found
   break;
}
```